# Hangfire in asp.net core webapi problem with DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

When I execute background job, and I try to resolve all dependencies, I get the exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MyProj.DAL.ApplicationContext'.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>
> Object name: 'ApplicationContext'
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()

My code - in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
services.AddHangfire(cfg => cfg
     .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
     .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
     .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
     .UseMemoryStorage());
        
services.AddHangfireServer();
```

in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ContainerJobActivator(provider));

app.UseHangfireDashboard()
```

and

```
public class ContainerJobActivator : JobActivator
{
    private IServiceProvider _container;

    public ContainerJobActivator(IServiceProvider container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
    {
        return _container.GetService(type);
    }
}
```

My DBContext

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().
            AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseNpgsql("server=localhost;port=5432;database=database;uid=root;password=password;"));
```

Comment: How did you register your Entity Framework context? Do you ever dispose it? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have added the example, thank you

Comment: Please show the code where you enqueue your job.
This may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975509/1236044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need resolve IServiceScopeFactory in our job, than get our service

```
using (var scope = _factoryScope.CreateScope())
{
      _articleRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IArticleRepository>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

     // your job here.....

 }
```

Comment: Even though your solution works, it corresponds to a ServiceLocator pattern, which is not considered good practice. It adds uneeded dependency to ServiceProvider, and probably FactoryScope, which make the code more complex and trickier to test.
You should look for a better solution. I guess your problme comes from the way you enqueue your job.

Comment: it's just philosophy, please offer your solution to the problem

Comment: If you say so, clean coding is philosophy. As already mentionned, if you don't post the code enqueueing the job, I don't see how I could help.