# My Hangfire job fires, but nothing happens and there are no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm having an issue where my Hangfire job is being fired, but nothing happens and there are no errors.

So in my Configure method within Startup.cs I configure the Hangfire job:

```
using (var context = new OspSpaceExplorerContext())
{
    MissionComms msc = new MemailAlertingProcessor(context);
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("[CRITICAL] - Process OrbitTime Notices :: CRITICAL",
   () => msc .ProcessOrbitTimeNotices(), Cron.Daily);
}
```

The method that the job fires is here. It sends out an email if certain conditions are met:

```
public void ProcessOrbitTimeNotices()
{
    var alertDate = DateTime.Today;
    
    var missions = _context.Mission
        .Include(m => m.Commander)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var mission in missions)
    {
        var dateTrigger = (int)Math.Round((mission.MissionDate - alertDate).TotalDays);

        switch (dateTrigger)
        {
            case 90:
                _commService.SendCommsAlert(
                    mission,
                    mission.Commander, 0090);
                break;
            case 31:
                _commService.SendCommsAlert(
                    mission,
                    mission.Commander, 0071);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I manually trigger the Hangfire job, it works and there no errors.  But the emails are not being sent out.  I made sure for testing, that the conditions are being met.

Just to make sure, I copied and pasted the code above into a controller.

When I hit the controller, it is working! The emails are sent out.

```
[HttpGet("ExpiringMissions")]
public  List<Mission> ExpiringMissions()
{
... same code as above
}
```

I am not sure why the Hangfire job doesn't work.  In the Hangfire dashboard, I don't see any errors when I manually trigger it.  It runs successfully. But the emails are not sent out.

Is there something wrong with Hangfire?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add logging to the code?

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you are trying to serialize and deserialize a context (that's how hangfire works under the hood)
You need to set up dependency injection and use the generic version of AddOrUpdate as in this :
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958728/1236044

Comment: @jbl Thanks! So I just need to remove the `using` directive in Startup.cs and replace it with this? `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ProcessOrbitTimeNotices>`?

Comment: @jbl hi so I started to change my code as you suggested...but I'm not sure if I need to inject `startup.cs` with the `context` or the `ProcessOrbitTimeNotices()` method...or both?

Comment: You need to do scoped service registration for `OspSpaceExplorerContext` and `MemailAlertingProcessor` and then remove all the using and "just" write :
`RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MemailAlertingProcessor>("[CRITICAL] - Process OrbitTime Notices :: CRITICAL",
   map => map.ProcessOrbitTimeNotices(), Cron.Daily);`